# MessageBox error

Tags: android, messagebox

Hi I just want to ask why is that I can't start my program it always shows an error when I start with MessageBox or AlertBox. What I'm trying to make is that if the player haven't answered more than 15 questions in the beginner stage he cant go on the learner stage and when he clicked the learner it will show a message box that he needs to answer 10+ answer to be able to go to next roundhere is my code

```
public class Menu extends Activity 
{

private Integer beginnerAns = 0;


Button beginner, learner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle MenuButtons) 
{
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(MenuButtons);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    beginner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner);
    learner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLearner);

    beginner.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
    learner.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);

}

View.OnClickListener myOnlyhandler = new View.OnClickListener(){
public AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(Menu.this);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnBeginner:
        Intent openBeginner = new Intent("com.thesis.logipic.BEGINNER");
        startActivity(openBeginner);
    break;
    case R.id.btnLearner:
        if (beginnerAns < 15)
        {
            dlgAlert.setMessage("wrong password or username");
            dlgAlert.setTitle("Error Message...");
            dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
            dlgAlert.create().show();
        }
        else
        {
        Intent openLearner = new Intent("com.thesis.logipic.GAMEPLAY");
        startActivity(openLearner);
        }
    break;
    }
}
};

}
```

and the **logcat**

```
10-06 21:00:28.673: D/AndroidRuntime(561): Shutting down VM
10-06 21:00:28.692: W/dalvikvm(561): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.thesis.logipic/com.thesis.logipic.Menu}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3526)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams.<init>(AlertController.java:743)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:273)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at com.thesis.logipic.Menu$1.<init>(Menu.java:38)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at com.thesis.logipic.Menu.<init>(Menu.java:37)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
10-06 21:00:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `super` must be the first thing you do.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle MenuButtons) 
{
    super.onCreate(MenuButtons);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    beginner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner);
    learner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLearner);

    beginner.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
    learner.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);

}
```

#### Edit:

I think I see the error now. You're trying to make a call to View.OnClickListener before `onCreate` is called:

```
public class Menu extends Activity 
{

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle MenuButtons) 
    {
        super.onCreate(MenuButtons);
        ...

    }

    View.OnClickListener myOnlyhandler = new View.OnClickListener(){
         ...
    };

}
```

Instead you should make the call inside onCreate:

```
public class Menu extends Activity 
{

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle MenuButtons) 
    {
        super.onCreate(MenuButtons);
        ...

        View.OnClickListener myOnlyhandler = new View.OnClickListener(){
             ...
        };

    }


}
```

This allows the activity to be created before you attempt to set up the listener.

Even better, you could be [applying this onClickListener to the Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html):

```
public class Menu extends Activity 
{

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle MenuButtons) 
    {
        super.onCreate(MenuButtons);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        ...
    };

}
```

The hint which led me to this was the stack trace line:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()`

What system services could you possibly be requesting? The View.OnClickListener!

As a general rule, when it comes to Java, you don't want to instantiate items outside of any methods or constructors. For example:

```
class A {
    B b = new B();

    A(){

    }
}
```

You would want to instantiate items inside the constructor:

```
class A {
    B b;

    A(){
        b = new B();
    }
}
```

Comment: double super.onCreate(MenuButtons)?

Answer (score 0):

Why not implement onClickListener on the activity. In your code you are creating a refercence to the context of de activity before you're onCreate was called so the context is not available. The point netinept makes of declaring attributes in the class and then instantiating them inside the constuctor/methode is also a good thing to do. In Android you don't typically have to use a constructor for activities or fragments cause there are lifecycle methodes that are called. See the android doc for more info [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

If you you really require a context before the activity/fragment is created you need to make a static methode in your Application class wrapper that returns the Application context. This can lead to leaks if not used correctly so only do this if you know what your doing.

Below a code example that should work better.

```
public class Menu extends Activity implements onClickListener {
   public AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert;

   public void onCreat() {
       super.onCreate(MenuButtons);
       ....
       beginner.setOnClickListener(this);
       learner.setOnClickListener(this);
       dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       switch(v.getId()) {
       case R.id.btnBeginner:
           Intent openBeginner = new Intent("com.thesis.logipic.BEGINNER");
           startActivity(openBeginner);
       break;
       case R.id.btnLearner:
           if (beginnerAns < 15) {
               dlgAlert.setMessage("wrong password or username");
               dlgAlert.setTitle("Error Message...");
               dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
               dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
               dlgAlert.create().show();
           } else {
               Intent openLearner = new Intent("com.thesis.logipic.GAMEPLAY");
               startActivity(openLearner);
           }
       break;
       }
    }
}
```